# Convolution of trigonometric polynomial $P$ with function $G$ such that $\widehat G(m)=m$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

Assume $G\in L^1(\mathbb{T})$ is any function such that $\widehat G(m)=m$ for all $m$ such that $|m|\leq n\ $. show that for any trigonometry polynomial $P$ of degree at most $n$, $P'=P *G$.

let $P(x)=\sum _{|m|\leq n}a_m \ e^{imx}$. then $P'(x)=\sum _{|m|\leq n}im   \ a_m \ e^{imx}$

\begin{align}
(P *G)x &=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}P(y)G(x-y)dy\\
&=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\sum _{|m|\leq n}a_m \ e^{imy}\right)G(x-y)dy
\end{align}

what can we do after that.i do not understand how idota will appear in this expression.

any hint

Comment: Are you sure you aren't missing an $i$ somewhere? From my calculations I get $P' = i (P * G)$.